# How to represent "." with Qt::Key_ enum?

Tags: qt, qt4.7

I checked document , but i didn't seem to find the corresponding enum definition for `.` , which `Qt::Key_` is that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run a small modification to code I had to capture the value. It comes as 46 decimal, which corresponds to `Key_Period = 0x2e` in qnamespace.h

```
bool MyClass::event( QEvent* e )
{
    if ( e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress )
    {
        QKeyEvent* ev = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>( e );
        int debug = ev->key();
    }
    return QDialog::event( e );
}
```